# Getting folder names from text file

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have a file list in a text file. How can I get only folder names from this text file ? (folders with the same name will be written once)

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6     
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0  
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.19.4  
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1.6.7   
/usr/bin/rakconvert  
/usr/bin/python-config  
/usr/bin/winecpp  
/usr/bin/wine  
/usr/bin/regedit  
/usr/bin/pycompile  
/usr/bin/msiexec
```

The content of this `1.txt` file. If the output I want:

```
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/  
/usr/bin
```

All the searches I've done are about sending the file list to a file. "cat, dirname", etc. I didn't add them here because I used a lot of code.

Sorry for the lack of my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treating this as a pure text-processing issue (i.e. ignoring the fact that Unix filenames can contain newlines, which is the reason you would not normally store pathnames in text files unless you know they are sane), we may remove anything after the last `/` character on each line and get the unique results through

```
$ sed 's,/[^/]*$,,' 1.txt | sort -u
/lib/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/bin
```

The `sed` expression `s,/[^/]*$,,` (which could also be written `s/\/[^/]*$//`) will remove anything matching `/[^/]*$`, i.e. a slash followed by any number of non-slash characters (through to the end of the line).

The `sort -u` at the end sorts the result a retains only the unique entries.  If the data is already sorted, you could use `uniq` instead.

Comment: Sen müthişsin. Tam kod açıklaması isteyecektim. Zaten yazdınız. Teşekkür ederim.